# Use Socket.io to get live JSON. Data From DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Following some tips on stuck overflow and on some groups,namely to adapt live the information received in json format.

**This is the first attempt**

I exposed the variable io from **server.js**.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || '7000';

const server = app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server Is Running!!!!`);
});

let io = require('socket.io')(server); 

-------
module.exports = io;
```

Also in the  **server.js** file I read on the internet information about mongo db live streem.

```
//Live Stream
const connection = mongoose.connection;

   connection.once("open", () => {
       //Live Stream - Posts 
      const observePosr_changes = connection.collection("posts").watch();
          //Observe change in Data Base
         observePosr_changes.on("change", (change) => {
             //console.log('changes right now ->',change);
            switch (change.operationType) {
                //create request
                case "insert":
                break;    
                //patch/put request
                case "update":
                //Update posts 
                break;  
                //delete request
                case "delete":
               //Update posts  
                break;  
            }
       });


  });
```

In the **controller directory,** in the **postController.js** file I made the following changes.

***controller/postController.js***

```
const socket = require('./server').io;
```

After importing I made the following changes in the same file.

```
exports.getAllPosts = catchAsync(async(req,res,next)=>{ 
     const getAll = await Post.find();

     socket.emit('getPosts_socket',getAll);

     socket.on('getPosts_socket',(getAll)=>{
         res.status(200).json({
           status:"success",
           length:getAll.length,
           data:{
               post:getAll
           }
         });
     });

  });
```

And in the **server.js** file I made the following updates

```
//Live Stream
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", () => {
  //Live Stream - Posts 
  const observePosr_changes = connection.collection("posts").watch();
    //Observe change in Data Base
    observePosr_changes.on("change", (change) => {
        //console.log('changes right now ->',change);
        switch (change.operationType) {
            //create request
            case "insert":
                //Create posts
                io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
                    console.log(`Socket start ${socket.id}`);
                    
                    //Recive event
                   socket.on('getPosts_socket', (data)=>{
                       socket.broadcast.emit('getPosts_socket',data);
                   });
                  
               });
            break;    
            //patch/put request
            case "update":
               //Update posts ->  operationType function 
            break;  
            //delete request
            case "delete":
               //Update posts ->  operationType function 
            break;  
          }
       });

 });
```

But it doesn't work and I have the following errors.

```
/*(node:1020) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'io' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)*/

/*TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
at C:\Users\Alex PC\Desktop\Authentification System  Node JS,Express,JsonWebToken\controllers\postController.js:115:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)*/
```

On the next test in the controller I tried to return the function inside another function and **io** became a parameter
***controller/postController.js***

```
    exports.getAllPosts = (socket)=>{ 

       return async (req,res)=>{

          const getAll = await Post.find();


          socket.emit('getPosts_socket',getAll);

          socket.on('getPosts_socket',(getAll)=>{
             res.status(200).json({
                status:"success",
                length:getAll.length,
                data:{
                   post:getAll
                }
             });
         });
       }

   };
```

And in **server.js** I imported information

```
const someController = require('./controllers/postController').getAllPosts(io);
```

But no more json information is sent and the application has crashed.

What I wanted to do is that when posting or deleting a json ad from api to adapt live without the need for refreshments.
[image]

Comment: You're exporting the `io` object, but trying to import an `io` property. Export your `io` object as `module.exports.io = io;`

Comment: the same problem

Comment: I dosen't recive any data and it give the same error,what I made in server I change module.exports.io = io;  and in controller directory const socket = require('./server').io; but isn;t work properly.